# query results to json laravel 5

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel-5

I want to be able to use query results from laravel in a cascading drop down list in my application view.

To begin with, I just want to see the query results translated into something I can use in a dropdown in laravel.

I have the following code:

```
$accounts = json_encode(DB::table('accounts')->join('Bookmakers', 'bookmakers.id', '=', 'accounts.bookmaker_id')->get());
```

And this yields:
    (from a dd($accounts))

```
"[{"id":"1","customer_id":"1","bookmaker_id":"1","balance":"0","profit":"0","created_at":"2016-01-28 17:44:33","updated_at":"2016-01-28 17:44:33","name":"William Hill","type":"Bookmaker","commission":"0"},{"id":"2","customer_id":"1","bookmaker_id":"2","balance":"0","profit":"0","created_at":"2016-01-28 17:44:33","updated_at":"2016-01-28 17:44:33","name":"Betfred","type":"Bookmaker","commission":"0"},{"id":"3","customer_id":"1","bookmaker_id":"3","balance":"0","profit":"0","created_at":"2016-01-28 17:44:33","updated_at":"2016-01-28 17:44:33","name":"Skybet","type":"Bookmaker","commission":"0"},{"id":"1","customer_id":"2","bookmaker_id":"1","balance":"0","profit":"0","created_at":"2016-01-28 17:44:33","updated_at":"2016-01-28 17:44:33","name":"William Hill","type":"Bookmaker","commission":"0"},{"id":"2","customer_id":"2","bookmaker_id":"2","balance":"0","profit":"0","created_at":"2016-01-28 17:44:33","updated_at":"2016-01-28 17:44:33","name":"Betfred","type":"Bookmaker","commission":"0"},{"id":"3","customer_id":"2","bookmaker_id":"3","balance":"25","profit":"0","created_at":"2016-01-28 17:44:33","updated_at":"2016-01-28 17:44:33","name":"Skybet","type":"Bookmaker","commission":"0"},{"id":"6","customer_id":"2","bookmaker_id":"6","balance":"100","profit":"0","created_at":"2016-01-28 17:44:33","updated_at":"2016-01-28 17:44:33","name":"DS","type":"Exchange","commission":"2"}]"
```

This looks largely ok.

I'm trying to assign this to a javascript variable in my view:

```
var accountData = {{ $accounts }};
```

but it comes out like this...

```
var accountData =     [{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;customer_id&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;bookmaker_id&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;balance&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;profit&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;created_at&quot;:&quot;2016-01-28 17:44:33&quot;,&quot;updated_at&quot;:&quot;2016-01-28 17:44:33&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;William Hill&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;Bookmaker&quot;,&quot;commission&quot;:&quot;0&quot;},{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;2&quot;,&quot;customer_id&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;bookmaker_id&quot;:&quot;2&quot;,&quot;balance&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;profit&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;created_at&quot;:&quot;2016-01-28 17:44:33&quot;,&quot;updated_at&quot;:&quot;2016-01-28 17:44:33&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Betfred&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;Bookmaker&quot;,&quot;commission&quot;:&quot;0&quot;},{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;3&quot;,&quot;customer_id&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;bookmaker_id&quot;:&quot;3&quot;,&quot;balance&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;profit&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;created_at&quot;:&quot;2016-01-28 17:44:33&quot;,&quot;updated_at&quot;:&quot;2016-01-28 17:44:33&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Skybet&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;Bookmaker&quot;,&quot;commission&quot;:&quot;0&quot;},{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;customer_id&quot;:&quot;2&quot;,&quot;bookmaker_id&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;balance&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;profit&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;created_at&quot;:&quot;2016-01-28 17:44:33&quot;,&quot;updated_at&quot;:&quot;2016-01-28 17:44:33&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;William Hill&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;Bookmaker&quot;,&quot;commission&quot;:&quot;0&quot;},{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;2&quot;,&quot;customer_id&quot;:&quot;2&quot;,&quot;bookmaker_id&quot;:&quot;2&quot;,&quot;balance&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;profit&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;created_at&quot;:&quot;2016-01-28 17:44:33&quot;,&quot;updated_at&quot;:&quot;2016-01-28 17:44:33&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Betfred&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;Bookmaker&quot;,&quot;commission&quot;:&quot;0&quot;},{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;3&quot;,&quot;customer_id&quot;:&quot;2&quot;,&quot;bookmaker_id&quot;:&quot;3&quot;,&quot;balance&quot;:&quot;25&quot;,&quot;profit&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;created_at&quot;:&quot;2016-01-28 17:44:33&quot;,&quot;updated_ ...etc
```

Can anyone tell me what I should be doing to get the data into a json format in my view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help:

```
var accountData = {!! $accounts !!};
```

When using `{!! $var !!}` the Blade engine won't escape your data.